# Knockout JS Iterate a array of object using JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, knockout.js

Below is my JSON response. I need to use knockout foreach to iterate through this array and display this array as a accordion. In this case "Nissan" will be accordion title and clicking on it expand to show other details. I could not find a way to print the key ("Nissan" or "Ford") and create a accordion correctly.It will be a dynamic array and key will be different. I think I would need nested foreach and ran into issues when iterates the second. Thanks in advance.

```
  var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.entries =
       {
        "Nissan": [
            {"model":"Sentra", "doors":4},
            {"model":"Maxima", "doors":4}
        ],
        "Ford": [
            {"model":"Taurus", "doors":4},
            {"model":"Escort", "doors":4}
        ]
}
    ;


<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: entries">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="foreach: $parent.data()">
            <a href="#" data-bind="text: model"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A7ppE/107/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON data uses an object to map the brand to an array of models, i.e. "Nissan" -> [...], "Ford" -> [...].  When usually dealing this this kind of data, I use a ko.computed() to convert the object map into an array of objects, usually adding the necessary functions and observables.

I posted a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/erbronni/L1kLdLvu/) using nested lists instead of a table. Clicking on the brand expands/collapses the sublist of car models.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: entries">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="text: brand, click: toggle"></a>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: models, visible: visible">
      <li data-bind="text: model"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also, order is not guaranteed when iterating over the properties of an object.  In the code below, the list is sorted to ensure a consistent order.  It is also a best practice to check that the property is on the object using `hasOwnProperty` and isn't inherited from the prototype chain when using an object as a map.

Also note that I stick the JSON response into an observable and then generate the list of entries in a computed observable.  This ensures that if new JSON data is set, the computed observable will automatically update.

```
var ViewModel = function() {
var self = this;
self.cars = ko.observable({
  "Nissan": [{
    "model": "Sentra",
    "doors": 4
  }, {
    "model": "Maxima",
    "doors": 4
  }],
  "Ford": [{
      "model": "Taurus",
      "doors": 4
    }, {
      "model": "Escort",
    "doors": 4
  }]
});
self.entries = ko.computed(function() {
  var list = [],
  entryVM,
  data = self.cars();
  for (var brand in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(brand)) {
      entryVM = new EntryViewModel(brand, data[brand]);
      list.push(entryVM);
    }
  }
  return list.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.brand < b.brand) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.brand > b.brand) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
});
};
```

For each entry a separate view model is created, `EntryViewModel`, that encapsulates the values and interaction. In this case, toggling the visibility of the model list is encapsulated in the inner view model, so the main view model doesn't need to concern itself with the inner view model's state.

```
var EntryViewModel = function(brand, models) {
  var self = this;
  self.brand = brand;
  self.models = models;
  self.visible = ko.observable(false);
  self.toggle = function() {
    self.visible(!self.visible());
  }
```

};